# Amazon SNS - Texting STOP to short code

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

What happens on the AWS backend when a user with an active subscription to a topic texts STOP to the AWS short code (30304)?

The Amazon documentation implies that they will no longer receive messages.

Does this mean that the subscription gets deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If the phone number is subscribed to an Amazon SNS topic, opting out does not remove the subscription, but SMS messages will fail to deliver to that subscription unless you opt in the phone number."

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_manage.html

You can opt the number back in via the console or an AWS SDK (instructions available in the same link).